# Regex pattern to match Titles and #s in pairs as an array

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to build a database of car dimensions, with raw data as follows:

```
Length 4638
Width 1825
Height 1384
Wheelbase 2810
Track (f) 1545
Track (r) 1594
Weight, unladden (G37) 1740
```

Each line contains the title, ie. "Length", "Track (f)" or "Weight, unladden (G37)" followed by the raw numeric only dimension.

The kicker is that the title can have #s within it, but the actual dimension should not include any non alpha characters, so that is how I would differentiate the two.

The pattern i'm working with right now is
**`/([a-z]+) ([0-9]+)/gi`**

However, the problem with this pattern is that its not able to handle the compex titles, such as Track (f) or Weight, unladden (G37)

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want to put the entire title in one capture group and the numbers? If so, why are you only matching letters then? Or do you intend the extra characters to be part of another capture group?

Comment: @remyabel Yes exactly, sorry I wasnt clear.  I want the title to be in one capture groupd and the #s in a second group.  The ultimate goal is to take this data and put it into a database of Titles and #s

Comment: Then why can't you just do `(.*)\s([0-9]+)`?

Comment: @remyabel Wow, seems to work! can you make that an answer so I can mark you correct?

Comment: But it's so painfully obvious though. Just post it yourself.

Comment: The `g` modifier is not available in PHP; it is a Javascript modifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is : `(.*)\s([0-9]+)`

Credit to @remyabel !